# How to launch multiple instances of microsft edge browser and collect their Process Ids

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge

How can I launch multiple edge browsers, that too in private mode and then get the process Ids. Also, is there any way to say that they should all be in different browser sessions and shouldn't share?

Comment: So when I click on New Window, it opens up a new instance. Are you saying that it is not a new instance? Even in that case, lets say I want to launch a private browsing session from command line, is that possible?