# Make Microsoft Edge shortcuts open up separate windows?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, browser-tabs

I just started using Microsoft's Edge.

When creating URL shortcuts or batch files for opening websites in Microsoft Edge, is there a way the websites can be opened up in new windows and not tabbed within Edge? I do know about the Ctrl + N shortcut and how to batch file for single websites.  When there is more then one instance, Edge seems to one want to tab everything.

Tabs are not for everyone.

There must be a syntax or menu I'm missing here. Internet Explorer can do this easy.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

Now that edge has switched to chromium base, there is an easy command line option which will achieve this `-new-window`

For example

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" -new-window https://www.google.com
```

#### Pre-chromium edge (broken links):

The only thing I can think of to force this is to use a webdriver in the shortcut command which should enable a forced new windows from the options [here](https://dev.modern.ie/platform/documentation/webdriver-commands/)

Specifically I think the new session would do it, although apparently there have been issues with [this](https://superuser.com/questions/952311/how-to-launch-multiple-instances-of-microsft-edge-browser-and-collect-their-proc) but I did see someone who had [success](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1779165/microsoft-webdriver-hangs-while-starting-new-edge-session-does-not-respond-to-further-requests)